# Replacing '.' and '-' in column values with empty space '' in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, regular-expression, replace

I have a shapefile that has a column named `"SBL"` with string values that contain points (.) and hyphens (-). However, I want to remove these points and hyphens, but so far I haven't been able to.

have tried both `replace` and `regexp_replace` functions in QGIS, but I haven't been successful yet. Below is a sample of these values:

[image: column value sample]

Also below is the code I tried:

```
 regexp_replace("SBL", '.', '')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try enclosing the `.` and `-` in square brackets for the regex:

```
regexp_replace("SBL", '[.-]', '')
```

Otherwise, you can chain  `replace` like this:

```
replace(replace("SBL", '.', ''), '-', '')
```

If you actually want to replace them by a space, as implied by your remark *"empty space"*, the replacement string should be `' '` (with a space between).

`123.14-2-16.1` would become `123 14 2 16 1`.

Using `''` (no space) will simply remove the characters from the input string.

`123.14-2-16.1` would become `123142161`.

Answer (score 3):

Your expression does not work as the period is a special character and therefore must be double-escaped:

```
regexp_replace("SBL", '\\.', '')

regexp_replace("SBL", '\\-', '')
```

OR

```
regexp_replace("SBL", '\\.|\\-', '')
```

but the best solution is to Matt