# Joining a CSV file to a shapefile based on string fields with different length values

Tags: qgis, shapefile, csv, spatial-join

I am trying to join a CSV file to a shapefile based on string fields with different length values. The values on the CSV file contain up to 16 digits where as the values on the shapefile contain 9 or 10 digits. I performed a normal join, but it was unsuccessful (all the columns from CSV file were null after the join). Below are the value samples of the columns that I want to join:

Shapefile: 111821211, 111821381, 11176248

CSV file: 1118200001021100, 1118200001038100, 1117600002048000

Below is a screenshot of the setting up the join:

[image: join setup screenshot]

I am not sure if virtual field is the right way to go.

Comment: This is just of them. There are up 70000 of them. About half of them won’t have a match

Comment: Yes. They are both string

Comment: Note. I hardly doubt. If there wasn’t do you know how I can make it work? I will add a screenshot shortly

Comment: Just added a screenshot of the join setup

Comment: Please don't present images of text values. Anyone who wants to help you now needs to retype the values. Making it easier for those who could help should be your goal.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I changed them as you requested

Comment: Assuming the common value is the first X characters of the longer string, you could import your CSV as a layer and use calculate field to truncate the values to the same number of characters as the shapefile, then perform the join.

Comment: And it's probably worth adding some values that you do expect to join, rather than those you don't. It would make providing a solution far easier.

Comment: @Matt I added some values that I expect to join. I just found out that the shapefile values ignore any 0s in the value, while CSV does not ignore them

Comment: In that case, would using an expression similar to the one in [your other question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/424823/128665) to calculate a new field in the CSV layer with no `0`s, and then performing the join using this new field, work?

Comment: It should work. I am right now creating the new column with no 0s. I am using R for it. I checked and it seems that it wasn't allowing me to add it through QGIS.

Comment: Providing sample data could help. If using QGIS, stick to Geopackage rather than shapefiles as these have a lot of limitations that might cause (additional) headaches.

Comment: It's not clear why you need to create this column in R. You can simply drag the CSV into the Layers panel of QGIS to import it as a layer (or go through `Layers -> Add Layer -> Add Delimited Text Layer...` if you need to fine tune settings), use Field Calculator to make the join field, then join with your shapefile layer. And consider seriously Babel's comment about using GeoPackage rather than shapefile. They are much more versatile.

Answer (score 0):

Kaveh, joins using text fields require that the text values in the two files are *identical*.  Based on the three samples that you provided, they are not identical; the csv data has extra zeros inserted. The solution, then, is to make the values in both files identical.  I propose to make them identical by editing the shapefile values so that they match the csv values.

Here's the workflow that I would use:

1. Starting without any joins, load the shapefile attribute table and select all records where the target field length = 9.
2. Using the Field Calculator, modify the target field (or a newly-added text field) by a) inserting 4 zeros starting at column 5, b) one zero starting at column 6, and c) three zeros at column 9.

Then repeat steps 1 and 2 where the target field length = 8. Save your edits.

3. Perform your join.  Voila! The shapefile target field (or its newly-created text field) will now match the csv join field.